# Access value in Object Typescript

Tags: typescript

i have question how to access a property inside the object.
i have a code something like this

```
public extentSource: object[];

this.extentSource = new Array<object>();

this.extentSource.push({
        id: md.deviceId,
        kameraName: md.label,
      });
```

if i just console.log(extentSource);

0: 
-id: 1 
-kameraName: canon 
1: 
-id: 2 
-kameraName: sony

and my question how to access kameraName for example i want only the kameraName Sony.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  As an aside... If you're using TypeScript, use TypeScript.  Define the type for your object(s) instead of making everything an `object` type.

Comment: If property access is new or strange to you, I suggest taking a basic typescript course to learn the basics. The solution - which I'm not sure you'll understand - is: Use an interface instead of `object` and then access it with `extentSource[0].kameraName`. If you do this with `object`, TS complains that `KameraName` doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want to find the object that has kameraName=="Sony", you can use `this.extentSource.find(x => x.kameraName === "Sony")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well give your little friend `extentSource` a decent type and you're good to go.  You're using typescript but at the same time you're not using typescript.

Just declare a `ExtentSource` interface like this:

```
interface ExtentSource {
  id: number
  kameraName: String
}
```

And now you can only put objects of type `ExtentSource` in the array.

You can access the attributes like this: `extentSource[0].kameraName` or `extentSource[0].id`.

---

And if you want to find an object with a specific value you can just do this:

```
this.extentSource.find((x) => x.kameraName === "Sony")
```